# Continuity of a jacobian, what does it mean?

Tags: analysis, continuity, vector-analysis, jacobian

If we consider $\vec{v} : R^n \rightarrow R^n$ a vector field and $J_v(\vec{x})$
$$[J_v(x)]_{ij}=\frac{\partial v_i}{\partial x_j}(\vec{x}) \quad \forall i,j \in \{1,...,n\}$$ its jacobian matrix at point $\vec{x}$ in $R^n$. Then what does it means that $J_v$ is continuous at point $\vec{a}$ in $R^n$ ? Because $J_v$ is a matrix ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that each entry of the matrix is continuous at $\vec a$.

Comment: Ok, but then can we say that there exists $\delta > 0 $ such that $\mid \mid J_v(\vec{x})\mid \mid_2 < \frac{1}{2}$ for all $x$ in $B_\delta(\vec{0})$ ? I mean, how does the norm of a matrix is defined ?

Comment: For instance,$$\lVert M\rVert=\sum_{1\leqslant i,j\leqslant n}\lvert a_{ij}\rvert.$$